# MathJax rendering of commas in numbers

Tags: angularjs, mathjax

When I include numbers with embedded commas (e.g. 3,456,789) in tex strings, They appear to have spaces after the commas (e.g. 3, 456, 789) when MathJax renders them. Is there some way to turn this off?

Comment: It's definitely just a work-around, but you could put braces around the commas to avoid unwanted spacing, as in `3{,}456{,}789` (the reason is that tex interprets the comma as a list separator, which behaviour is inhibited if you group the comma by itself). As for just latex, [it's said](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133993/preserving-thousands-separator-with-siunitx) that the `siunitx` package would help (I don't know if that's in any way applicable to MathJax).

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/mjqLszoy/

Comment: This jsfiddle demonstrate's Andras Deak's solution: http://jsfiddle.net/mjqLszoy/1/

Comment: So, is this satisfactory as a solution? If so, should I add it as an answer?

Comment: Please do add it as an answer, so I can credit you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's definitely just a work-around, but you could put braces around the commas to avoid unwanted spacing, as in `3{,}456{,}789`. The reason is that `tex` interprets the comma as a list separator, which behaviour is inhibited if you group the comma by itself.