# How to configure MathJax to output thousands separators in constants?

Tags: mathjax

I am using MathJax to render formulas into HTML pages. I am using this HTML in the head of my document to configure and import MathJax:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    "HTML-CSS" : {
        availableFonts : ["STIX"],
        preferredFont : "STIX",
        webFont : "STIX-Web",
        imageFont : null
    }
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" async
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=AM_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

I have this formula that I would like MathJax to render:

```
`v = (pi w (w^2 a^2 + 2540 w a d)) / 10000000`
```

MathJax renders it like this:

[image: an equation rendered by MathJax]

Notice the large constants, especially 10000000, are difficult to understand without thousands separators. I would like MathJax to automatically insert thousands separators when it renders this equation. I have searched the MathJax documentation at http://docs.mathjax.org and searched using Google, but I can't find any mention of thousands separators in MathJax. I also found this StackOverflow question [MathJax rendering of commas in numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004337/mathjax-rendering-of-commas-in-numbers) with a workaround for TeX, but the work around doesn't work for me because I am rendering the formulas into HTML pages, not into a TeX document.

How can I configure MathJax to automatically output commas as thousands separators within a formula?

Comment: The TeX workaround works in MathJax's TeX input. A more complete example that shows your MathJax configuration would help. If you're using asciimath input, check http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/AsciiMath.html for `decimalsign`.

Comment: It seems to me that you are describing options for the input. I don't want to change the input. I want MathJax to automatically change the output. I want MathJax to automatically insert thousands separators when it renders the equation. I edited my question to make that clearer.

Comment: This kind of thing only works by modifying the input, which can be done programmatically. Again, what input are you using?

Comment: I thought that I stated the input in my question. If I didn't state the "input that I'm using" in my question, then I don't know what input I am using. How can I find the "input that I'm using"?