# mathjax commas in digits

Tags: mathjax, digits

This is a TeX legacy issue---it would have made more sense to require a whitespace when a whitespace is desired:  `12,123` is probably a number, while `12, 123` is probably a list.  Alas, it is what it is.

Related to [MathJax rendering of commas in numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004337/mathjax-rendering-of-commas-in-numbers), where the solution is suppression of spaces via `{,}`.  Works, but inconvenient.  Is there a way to make this automatic?

The hack in https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/169#issuecomment-2040235 is concerned with European vs Anglo.  The equivalent hack,

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("TeX Jax Ready",function () {
    MathJax.InputJax.TeX.Definitions.number =
      /^(?:[0-9]+(?:\,[0-9]{3})*(?:\{\.\}[0-9]*)*|\{\.\}[0-9]+)/
  });
</script>
```

solves the comma problem in `1,234.56` but now there is a space after the period (i.e., before 5).  I am not sure how the regex above works.  can someone help?

Comment: [following regex](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/169#issuecomment-356886198) worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the pattern to

```
/^(?:[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]*)*|\.[0-9]+)/
```

to allow `12,345.6` to be treated as a number, while `12, 345` is a list of two numbers.  In the original pattern, the `\{\.\}` requires a literal `{.}` (braces included), not just a decimal.